# Clickable hyperlink behind image

Tags: html, hyperlink, widget, linkedin-api

I'm using the [LinkedIn Profile widget](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1072) on my site and am using the `popup` version. Although it's functional, I don't like the little LinkedIn icon that's placed as I'm already using a larger LinkedIn icon. Is it possible to hide the smaller one? (I assume it's built into the class, but there may be an option somewhere?) If not, is it possible to overlap a hyperlink so that I can essentially hide the smaller icon behind the larger icon, but ensure the smaller one gets clicked if the large one is clicked on? (Hope that make sense :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a `style="background-image:none;"` to your link.

Comment: Thanks! At first it didn't work, but I added it via javascript (once everything on the page had loaded) and the image has gone.